# Help for changing image Magento

Tags: image

onClick How to change products color image in same box? my product view page not change the image... it goes on an other page... http://crazyprices.pk/electronics/samsung/samsung-glaxy-s6-edge.html

this is url if anyone have solution so please help me.. where i do changes for that.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Including a screenshot or further details may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what's logged in the console: `jQuery(...).CloudZoom is not a function`.  You are missing a js library for cloud zoom. Find out what is missing and add the js to the page.

Comment: Yes it is working now correctly..